# Storing geometry data in r packages

Tags: r, package

I read somewhere that creating custom functions and build them into packages is the best way to avoid repeating code and keeping several scripts, so i'm giving it a try.

`devtools::install_github("https://github.com/albersonmiranda/desigualdade")`

Here i'm trying to setup functions to shortcut some map plots.

## REPRODUCING

In `data-raw` Github repo folder, which i removed from .gitignore only for this thread, there's a script named data.R. Running it will give you an object named `censo_des`. It's a tibble with Brazil's 2010 census and municipalities geometry data.

I can then load the functions in `/R` folder and run `RM("RJ", n.nomes = 2)` for plotting Rio de Janeiro's map, with `geom_label()` showing names for top 2 mucipalities of higher and lower per capita income for black and white people.

[image]

## QUESTION

Running `usethis::use_data(censo_des, overwrite = TRUE)` to create `.rda` file and store it in `/data` folder seems to change `censo_des` structure and it's no longer a tibble. When i install the package, if i try to run `censo_des` i get the error message `Error: Input must be a vector, not a sfc_GEOMETRY/sfc object.` and if i try `RM("RJ")` i get `Error: Can't slice a scalar`.

I guess my issue is how to proper store `sfc_GEOMETRY` data in packages. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to import `sf` package to handle geometry data. It isn't a regular tibble or data frame. Once i imported, everything worked fine.